# Как отредактировать библиотеку подключенную через Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build-automation

Установил библиотеку через Gradle. Есть ли возможность исправить Gradle этой библиотеки? я прошелся по иерархии Android Studio но никакого Gradle данной либы не нашел, но на гитхабе она есть.

Где нужно смотреть Gradle скачанной либы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы через зависимости скачиваете AAR файл. Его нельзя редактировать. Если нужно что-то подправить в библиотеке, то:

1. Клонируйте проект с гитхаба.
2. Меняйте, что хотите.
3. Используйте в вашем проекте как библиотеку.

Но в таком случае будут проблемы в будущем, если либа обновится, придётся мерджить и решать конфликты с вашими изменениями.

Comment: Ясно, а можно этому автору написать в гитхаб чтобы он подправил? ток как не знаю

Comment: @xTIGRx а что не так с библиотекой? Обычно если находят косяки, то пул реквесты создают.

Comment: Там в манифесте стоит 15 версия, нужно 11 хотя бы поставить, а то не компилиться

Comment: @xTIGRx если там стоит 15, то явно не просто так. Предполагаю, что либа использует что-то из 15 sdk. Даже если вы выставите там 11 версию, то сама библиотека может не скомпилиться.

Comment: А чем смысл выпускать такие либы которые работают от 15 версии? более 1000 моделей на ветер пустил данный автор либы. Да и нет в 15 ничего такого,новшества пришли из 8 и 14

Comment: @xTIGRx незачем поддерживать старьё. Уже давно пора ставить минимальную платформу 4.0+

Comment: Это вы так считаете, а другим людям вы тоже будете телефоны покупать с версией 4.0?))

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/dashboards/index.html Android 2.3 всего пара процентов от общего числа. Да, можно на них забить.

Comment: Не всегда. К примеру приложения раздающие небольшие кредиты часто рассчитаны на прослойку общества кому не хватает пары копеек дожить до следующей зарплаты. Если к этому добавить еще и целевую страну третьего мира где-нибудь в Африке то процент целевой аудитории <4.0 резко подскакивает

Comment: @Arderun всё зависит от того, что разрабатывается и под какую ЦА. Для большинства приложений можно забить на < 4.0, чем тратить в 2 раза больше времени на разработку ради этого старья.

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариев под вопросом видно что вы ищите способ изменить minSdk версию библиотеки которую подтягиваете. Для подобных вещей можно использовать ManifestMerger(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html глава: **Override  for imported libraries**) записывается это в виде:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="20" android:minSdkVersion="11"
      tools:overrideLibrary="ваша.библиотека"/>
```

В gradle так сделать не выйдет, зато можно скомпилировать бибилотеку с флагом force тем самым проигнорировав minSdk.

```
dependencies {
              ...
    compile ('ваша.библиотека'){force=true}
              ...
}
```

Comment: Но остается большая вероятность того, что библиотека, заявленная с minSDK15 на SDK11 работать **не будет**

Comment: Само собой что человек  перед любым использованием подобной библиотеки проверяет версию sdk на  минимальные требованиями указанные для библиотеки(когда нужна к примеру какая-то feature ,а людей с старыми версиями андроид можно проигнорировать). в остальном зависимости библиотеки уже входят в нее или добавляются отдельно. Так что шансы не плохие, хотя если есть менее требовательная версия то конечно нужно смотреть прежде всего в ее сторону.